# MooseX::Getopt - canonical way to specify usage message

Tags: perl, moose

What's the usual way to include "usage" text in a program using MooseX::Getopt?  (i.e. running `myprog --usage` should print something like "myprog: make everything great")

The MooseX::Getopt documentation says:

"If Getopt::Long::Descriptive is installed and any of the following command line params are passed, the program will exit with usage information. You can add descriptions for each option by including a documentation option for each attribute to document."

but I'm having trouble parsing that last sentence.

Comment: I didn't word this question very well, but the effect I'm looking for can be achieved by overriding _usage_format in the consumer of MooseX::Getopt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moose attributes can take a [documentation option](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aAttributes#The-documentation-option):

```
has foo => (
  ...,
  documentation => "The foo attribute foofles the program",
);
```